# Yii2, In unit testing, how to autoload an interface with Yii2 way, not by composer

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii2

In Yii2 basic template, I have an unit test class that those class will be implement an interface as a contract.

My directory looks like this:

```
tests/unit
├── _bootstrap.php
└── models
    ├── AgamaTest.php        (a class)
    └── ICrudUnitTest.php    (an interface)
```

Then, ICrudUnitTest.php looked like this:

```
<?php

namespace tests\unit\models;

interface ICrudUnitTest
{
    public function testValidation();

    public function testInsertWithValidAttribute();

    public function testFindById();

    public function testDeleteById();

    public function testUpdateById();
}
```

Here is the thing, The problem is when I want to implement those interface like this:

```
<?php

namespace tests\unit\models;

use app\models\Agama;
use Codeception\Specify;
use Codeception\Test\Unit;
use UnitTester;

class AgamaTest extends Unit implements ICrudUnitTest

{
    use Specify; 
    some-code-here ....
}
```

Then running like this via terminal:

```
codecept run unit models/AgamaTest.php
```

Its said : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Interface 'tests\unit\models\ICrudUnitTest' not found in /var/www/html/tests/unit/models/AgamaTest.php:10

You know, with composer I can use autoload psr-4 like this :

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "tests\\": "tests"
  }
}
```

then just `composer dump-autoload`, that it will be works as charmed.

As Yii2 developer, How to autoload those interface with Yii2 way, not by composer?
Is there any configuration that I need to change, or add in some config?

Any help, it so appreciated ....

Comment: I didn't test it but I think adding `@tests` alias and pointing in to the `tests` folder in config that is used by tests should be enough. The config is probably in `config/test.php`.

Comment: Can you show us what does your `config/test.php` look like?